# How to recreate server in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I was having some error when trying to restart the server today, so i deleted it thinking it would be easy to recreate it. I am not being able to find the steps to recreate what i deleted. 
I am using the Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE

Comment: Hopefully someone made a backup.

Answer (score 2):

@gerrytan and @mserioli 's answer is the best answer

It so simple follow these steps

> Window **->** Preferences **->** Server **->** Runtime Environments **->** Add
>
> Select the type of runtime **->** next
>
> Give the correct installation directory of your server and  name of
> the server  **->** Finish

Answer (score 0):

The server panel of STS is actually the same as Eclipse for which you can read the manual: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrtins.html